# Give multiple class names to one rule

Tags: html, css, hover

Im creating 2 bounce animations, one that bounces once, and one that is infinite. Since the hover states are the same for both i put both class names into the hover rule, but it didnt work and i had to put them in separate rules. Surely theres a way to have them in the same rule to condense the code?

Below is the code that doesnt work:

```
/* BOUNCE ICON ON HOVER */       
   @keyframes bounce {
    0%, 100%, 20%, 50%, 80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform:     translateY(0);
        transform:         translateY(0)
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        -ms-transform:     translateY(-30px);
        transform:         translateY(-30px)
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
        -ms-transform:     translateY(-15px);
        transform:         translateY(-15px)
    }
}
.bounce-icon {  
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.bounce-once-icon {  
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

.bounce-once-icon, .bounce-icon:hover {
  animation-name: bounce;
  -moz-animation-name: bounce;
}
```

I tried a few things:

```
.bounce-once-icon, .bounce-icon
.bounce-once-icon,.bounce-icon
.bounce-once-icon.bounce-icon
.bounce-once-icon .bounce-icon
```

Comment: There needs to be a :hover after both the selectors: .bounce-once-icon:hover, .bounce-icon:hover